# Tty vs User applications

Tags: linux, shell, kernel, tty, hardware

If terminal/console is mapped to a tty (teleTypewriter), then how does other applications like Google chrome, notepad etc.. Read input, output from the keyboard?

Answer (score 0):

The apps that you mention use X11 (or equivelent), not the tty.

The virtual terminals use a window in X11, the same as these apps. The virtual terminal windows provide a virtual tty.

X11 provides keyboard focus to one window at a time (the active window). To these apps it looks like they have their own keyboard, but (coincidentally) no one is typing when there is no keyboard focus.